# Why is SHA2-256 hash not the same between MySQL and MS SQL Express?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hash, sha256

I am building a reporting database and get data in CSV as well as from MS SQL Server. These are mostly personal records, tied together by SSN (well, not really SSN but something very similar). For security reasons, we are not storing the SSN, but rather the SHA2-256 hash of the SSN.

On MySql 5.6, I can simply use the built-in function:

```
sha2( string, 256).
```

For MS SQL Express (SQL Server 2008 running on Windows 7) I used this link (http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2009/09/19/strong-password-hashing-with-sql-server.aspx) to write an external UDF.

Each function should return the same string for the same argument .. and it does not. Even more puzzling is that the binary representation seems to be quite different:

```
MySql Output:   bfd6b995588ec54ce16871bc82a7ac86dd43a2c22309ea68e479a50043683937
MSSQL Output: 0x1B4F27012B7F6E7DA6563376E3CB560FCB07FDE2E33C6C3241A5D53885ABCF71
```

The MSSQL output is clearly a hex encoding (0-9, A-F) of the low and high 4 bit portions of each byte. But how does MySql represent the binary characters?
Ran the MySql queries both through SqlYog and through the DOS command-line ... no difference. 
I have checked the MySql documentation and everything else I could find on the web, no luck.

Comment: SHA is not encryption.

Comment: Your SQL Server called is adding a salt (but calling it a "vector" for some reason)

Comment: Please provide the input you used.

Comment: There is no 'salt' in the function: byte[] outputBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(memberIdBytes);

Comment: MySql statement: SELECT 'eins' AS plain, sha2( 'eins', 256) AS encrypted;

Comment: The question is first and foremost about why the MSSQL and the MySql outputs are so different.

Comment: You do know that SHA is for hashing and not for encryption?

Comment: I do ... sorry for the confusion ... I am hashing the SSNs, not encrypting them.

Comment: Hashing SSNs is bad for the same reason as hashing credit cards is bad - there is only a small number of possible inputs, so building a hash lookup table would be extremely trivial, negating the purpose of having them hashed. Look into encrypting instead of hashing these.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MySql returns the same hex codes as MSSQL, just in lowercase. I did correct my C# code and now both functions return the same string. Hurrayyyyyyy